# is string array possible in c++?

Tags: c++, arrays, string

As far as I know,in  C++ `string` is itself an array of `char`.

So my question is:
Is it  possible to have a String array in C++?

If yes please let me know the way to declare/handle it.

Comment: `std::string` from `#include <string>` is the class type for string in c++

Comment: Better [choose a good book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list). Will tell you everything you need to know about `std::string`.

Comment: What's wrong with `std::string`?

Comment: The proper type to use is `std::string` or `std::u16string`, if you want UTF16. And yes, you can create containers of strings.

Comment: _"String is itself an array of char"_ - no. C uses char arrays for strings, but doesn't have a type named String. C++ _can_ use those arrays, but `std::string` is mostly preferred.

Comment: Be careful not to mix up C with C++. You can compile C code with C++ but that doesn't make it a good idea

Comment: in c++ is c++ an array of characters?

Comment: In Java (up to Java 8), String is also an array of characters. It's just that you can't get at it, because it's declared a private field. Similarly with C++ strings. In C, they're a bit more explicit but you can still have arrays of char arrays. It's just that in C++ it's not recommended to use C strings. Stick to C++.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Of course it is:

```
// Requires <string> and <vector> includes
std::vector<std::string> foo = {"this", "is", "a", "string", "array"};
```

or

```
// Requires <string> and <array> includes
std::array<std::string, 3> foo = {"if", "you", "must"};
```

As a rule of thumb, *always* use `std::vector` unless you can think of a very good reason not to.

Comment: can this array be handled just like a normal array?

Comment: @JavaRookie: Indeed it can. C++11 is *very* powerful.

Comment: @JavaRookie You can use the subscript operator in the usual way. E.g. `foo[0]` to get the first string.

Comment: is #include<string.h> required for using this?

Comment: @JavaRookie `<string.h>` is a C header. We would have `<cstring>` in C++. And no, you need `<string>` instead.

Comment: then why does my turbo c++ want me to always say Code>#include<iostream.h</code>.

Comment: Or do you think my software is outdated?

Comment: @JavaRookie Turbo C++ is an ancient compiler which came before C++ had even reached its first official version. Use a compiler from this millenium, such as GCC or Clang.

Answer (score 7):

In modern C++, we try not to see strings as array of characters anymore. Some high-level tools from the Standard Library provide the level of indirection we need.

Array of five strings:

```
std::array<std::string, 5> = {"init.", "generously", "provided", "by", "Bathsheba" };
```

Dynamic array of strings:

```
std::vector<std::string> = { "as", "much", "strings", "as", "one", "wants" };
```

Please see their related documentation:

- [`std::string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string)
- [`std::array`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array)
- [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector)

Comment: Nice links at the bottom, making this answer useful. Feel free to pinch the initialisation from my answer.

Comment: @Bathsheba I'd like a `merge` button for those kind of cases.

Answer (score 5):

String is a type. As with any other type it is possible to define an array of strings in C++:

```
std::string myarray[] = {"Hello", "World", "Lorem"};
```

or:

```
std::vector<std::string> myarray = {"Hello", "World", "Lorem"};
```

or:

```
std::array<std::string, 3> myarray = {"Hello", "World", "Lorem"};
```

Be sure to include the `<string>` and other appropriate headers. Here is more info on [std::string](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) class template.

Answer (score 4):

Here is what you want literally:

```
#include <string>
// ...
std::string str_array[] = {"some", "strings", "in", "the", "array"};
```

But actually you'd better use `std::array` or `std::vector` as it shown in others answers.